# Creating a project based "level of effort remaining" visualization for project tracking and management

Tags: statistics, excel, project-planning

I am looking to create a tracker to help manage the current and future progress of a large engineering project. The project is made up of many subprojects each with their own tracker. This is an excel based tool and on a summary sheet I want a new column that would show the level of effort remaining to finish any given subproject. This is a useful metric because some tasks take weeks or months to complete while others my take an hour.  I am currently tracking the amount of time it takes to complete individual tasks and well as other averages and SDV relating to each category of task. My current solution is to take a sum of all the average tasks time to complete and the sum of all the major tasks time. Then I would subtract new completed tasks from the total task time, the closer this gets to the major task time, the level of effort metric will increase. I feel like there is a hole in this solution and I was curious if there a better solution to this?